# Bash: How do I pass "command not found" text into my trap function?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

I have the following:

**test.sh**

```
. Foo.sh

Foo.bar
Foo.baz
Foo.blah
```

and

**Foo.sh**

```
function Foo.bar() {
    echo 'I am a bar!'
}

function Foo.baz() {
    echo 'But, I am a baz!'
}

function Foo.error() {
    # I should suppress the 'command not found' error based on the pattern '^Foo\.([^:]+):'
    # If the pattern is matched, I'll need to perform some action based on the captured pattern.
}
trap Foo.error ERR
```

This is what I get when I run `test.sh`:

```
$ ./tesh.sh
I am a bar!
But, I am a baz!
./test.sh: line 5: Foo.blah: command not found
```

I would like to:

1. suppress the `command not found` error.
2. pass the `Foo.blah: command not found` text to `Foo.error()` to perform some action based on the error.

I suppose I could redirect errors to /dev/null like so:

```
./test.sh 2> /dev/null
```

But this is not as elegant as I'd like it to be. In any case, it still doesn't give my error() function access to the error text.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `test` to check if the command exists and it is executable? Like this:

```
if [[ -x /my/executable/file ]]; then
    echo "Oh, there we go!";
else
    echo "Oh damn! =(";
fi;
```

Cya!

Comment: Because the contents of `test.sh` would be written by someone else who would only know the very basic commands. My goal is to grab the error message and determine what to do based on the error message. Thanks for the suggestion though.